# Appium - A new session cannot be created. Activity used to start app doesn't exist or cannot be launched

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, appium

When I start Appium server with Application Path, Package, and Launch Activity selected the server starts with my application and I can run my test. When my test is done I quit the driver.

Next I try to run the same test again with the server already running. I have capabilities written in the TestFixtureSetUp (see below). However, I get the following error:

```
SetUp : System.InvalidOperationException : A new session could not be created. (Original error: Activity used to start app doesn't exist or cannot be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchable activity) (33)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.AppiumDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at MobileAutomationSample.AndroidSimpleTest.BeforeAll() in AndroidSimpleTest.cs: line 42
```

My code:

```
[TestFixture()]
public class AndroidSimpleTest
{
    private AppiumDriver driver;

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void BeforeAll()
    {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.SetCapability("appium-version", "1.2.4.1");
        capabilities.SetCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.SetCapability("platformVersion", "5.0");
        capabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "emulator-5554");
        capabilities.SetCapability("browserName", "");
        capabilities.SetCapability("app", "app-debug.apk");
        capabilities.SetCapability("appPackage", "com.company.app");
        capabilities.SetCapability("appActivity", "com.company.app.MainActivity");
        Uri androidUri = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
        driver = new AppiumDriver(androidUri, capabilities, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    }

    [TestFixtureTearDown]
    public void AfterAll()
    {
        driver.Quit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolute path needed to be provided for app capability. Once that was provided the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

just add `driver.closeapp()` and `driver.resetapp()` in `afterall` method